# Training agent to explore unknown environments doesn't work

Tags: artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

While reading a book on RL "Deep Reinforcement Learning Hands-On" By Maxim Lapan I tried to create my own agent and environment. The problem is that my agent does not seem to train properly.
I want to make an agent that can automatically explore (in the most efficient way) an indoor building. To do that, I created an Gym-like (and compatible) environment, here are the characteristics:

- Size: 100px by 100px
- Randomly generated at each reset using a Binary Space Partitioning
  algorithm (from here:
  https://arcade.academy/examples/procedural_caves_bsp.html)
- All is in grayscale
- Wall pixels correspond to a value of 0
- The agent, a 3x3 px square, has a value of 192
- The empty pixels have a value of 255
- The explored pixels have a value of 64
- For each action (up, down, left, right) the agent is moved by 1 pixel

I clipped the reward between -1 and 1 such as:

- If the agent explore new pixels: +1.0
- If the agent does not explore new pixels: -0.1
- If the agent hits a wall: -1.0

The win condition is if the agent has explored at least 98% of the pixel with also a reward of +1. Or it looses if the agent does not explore new pixels during 8000 frames.

Edit: One of the thing I think I'm doing wrong is giving rewards to the agent during the episode. So I was doing reward shaping without knowing what it actually was. From what I understand this can be tricky and difficult to correctly do.
I will try to only give reward at the end of the episode (0 during the episode) and basically ending it if the agent hits a wall, and the total reward will be the number of "special points" hit. I will try different variation of this to see if I can get the agent to learn something.

I used ray-casting to simulate the field-of-view of the agent. It starts with a blank screen and walls automatically appears in a radius of X pixels around the agent (If rays are not blocked by a wall).

[image: Environment example]

I tried using DQN with different enhancements, the code for those are from the book's author here: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Deep-Reinforcement-Learning-Hands-On-Second-Edition/tree/master/Chapter08

The model for the neural network is the following:

```
(0): Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=(8, 8), stride=(4, 4))
(1): ReLU()
(2): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(4, 4), stride=(2, 2))
(3): ReLU()
(4): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1))
(5): ReLU()

(0): Linear(in_features=5184, out_features=512, bias=True)
(1): ReLU()
(2): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=4, bias=True)
```

Input to the neural network:

- 1 frame of the environment: [1, 1, 100, 100] normalized from [0, 255]
  to [0, 1]

(I did not use frame stacking because there is no moving objects, except the agent at each state)

Hyperparameters (For basic DQN with replay buffer and target net):

- lr: 1e-3
- Replay size: 800 000 (max I can do with my ram)
- Replay start size: 50 000
- Sync target net: 10 000
- Epsilon starting at 1.0 and ending at 0.1 after 1 million frames
- Gamma: 0.99
- Batch size: 32

I tried two things to force the agent to explore:

- Leaving the environment as specified previously and hoping the
  rewards as well as the feedback the agent gets from the colored-coded
  "explored pixels" would be enough.
- Removing the explored pixels color and reward and adding special
  pixels (1px by 1px) of gray value 128. Each time the agent hit those
  pixels it would get a reward of +1 (Like apple or points in Pacman,
  Snake, etc.), those special pixels disappear when hit. To try to force the agent to seek and explore to find
  those special points. Seen below:

[image: Environment with special points]

The problem is that the agent does not seem to learn to explore the environment. It gets better scores with the randomness added by epsilon (or noise using Noizy Layers). But after that the agent seems to explore less and less and finally gets mostly stuck in corners. Same with the special points, it does not seem to try to get them. I tried different hyperparameters/rewards, tried basic DQN, adding enhancement (N-step, noizy layers, Double DQN, Dueling, etc.). I ran my code ranging from a few hours to 10 hours (on a 2080 super).

So I was wondering if maybe there is something wrong with my idea on how to get the agent to explore, maybe the rewards are wrong (I tried varying those), maybe there is something I am missing to get the agent to explore the map. Also I did not really touch the model's network, I might need to add more layers? Or maybe there is something wrong with the information I gave above. Also I know better methods exist A2C, A3C, PPO, etc. But my environment is not that different from an ATARI game that DQN can solve anyway.

If you have any ideas...

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to represent state as  **stacked** frames. Because if don't do that agent has no way of knowing the  **regions** already explored.